# ActionBarActivity imported by default when minSdkVersion is 11?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

Since ActionBar is supported for API above version 11, I set the minSdkVersion to that. 
But the empty activity comes with ActionBarActivity by default and I want to use ActionBar instead of ActionBarActivity.

Is it just normal? Tried creating some other new modules too. But they came up with the same result.
Do I have to change the whole thing to ActionBar by removing ActionBarActivity import?

I use java 1.7, Android API 21 on Android Studio. My target sdk level is 18.

Comment: But there are few differents... So if you wana ActionBar looks and acts similar (starting from 11)use appcompat version.... Also there is new stuff like Toolbar in api 21 which is implemented in appcompat.. Also part of material api is ported in appcompat... And appcompat needs ActionBarActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'd answer my own question coz I didn't get the answer I was looking for from here.

If you want to use `ActionBar` or `Activity` to extend your class but not `ActionBarActivity` then do not use new activity -> blank activity option.

Instead create the class in a package you prefer implement the whole activity from ground level. That helped me.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to have the same capabilities of Actionbar with ActionBarActivity import so there shouldn't be a need to replace ActionBarActivity to ActionBar. If I'm not mistaken ActionBarActivity actually has more libraries and maybe more useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `ActionBar` and the minimum sdk version that you support is 11 then you don't need to extend `ActionBarActivity`, you only need to extend `Activity`. Then to use your `ActionBar` you can call `getActionBar()` from within that Activity.

Comment: Problem is it's there by default. So now I've found a work around- not to use blank activity when creating new module.